# How to Remove Duplicate Numbers all at once in a list box in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Form1
   Private Sub Button10_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button10.Click
       ListBox1.Items.Add(0)
    End Sub

   Private Sub Button11_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button11.Click
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
   End Sub

   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        ListBox1.Items.Add(1)
   End Sub

   Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        ListBox1.Items.Add(2)
   End Sub

   Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        ListBox1.Items.Add(3)
   End Sub

   Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        ListBox1.Items.Add(4)
   End Sub

   Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        ListBox1.Items.Add(5)
   End Sub

   Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        ListBox1.Items.Add(6)
   End Sub

   Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
        ListBox1.Items.Add(7)
   End Sub

   Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
        ListBox1.Items.Add(8)
   End Sub

   Private Sub Button9_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click
        ListBox1.Items.Add(9)
   End Sub

   Private Sub Button12_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button12.Click

        Dim intNumRemoved As Integer 'The number to be removed
        Dim strInput As String 'To hold user input
        strInput = InputBox("Enter the item that you want to remove") 'prompt the user to enter the item to be removed

        If Integer.TryParse(strInput, intNumRemoved) Then 'Converting the user input from InputBox to an Integer
            ListBox1.Items.Remove(intNumRemoved)
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

1.The user is allowed to add digits 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 to a listbox using buttons.

2.The user is allowed to "clear" the list box with a button.

3.When the user clicks on the "Remove Item" button, the program will:

a.Allow the user to input the name of an item in an InputBox
   b.Remove all instances of items from the listbox even the duplicate ones

Comment: Should this have a vb.Net tag rather than vba?

Comment: How do you do the same thing multiple times? You use a loop.

Comment: By the way, you really ought to change the names of everything to something meaningful. If `Button1` to `Button9` correspond to those numbers being added to a list then that's fair enough. `Button10` for a `Button` that adds zero though? Not good. `Button11` and `Button12` are even worse in that context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

)

I know this is an older question, but maybe it will still help..

To remove all the numbers in your listbox you need to loop through each item and check if it is equal to the value inputted.

One thing to remember of course is that most things like ListBoxes,Lists,Arrays etc have zero-based indexes - means the first element starts at index 0)

Take a look at the list below - the left hand column is the position(index) in the list of the number, and the right hand column is the number itself.

0     4

1     9

2     5

3     1

4     4

5     7

6     3

7     3

8     6

9     2

10    8

Also, because of the way VB does loops, you need to go backwards. I'll try to explain ..

Below is code for the simplest loop

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 10

Next
```

When the loop first starts, the start point and end point of the loop are set in that first statement. They will never change. Look at this example

```
    Dim loopStart As Integer = 0
    Dim loopEnd As Integer = 10
    For i As Integer = loopStart To loopEnd

    Next
```

Pretty straight forward and works the same way as the first example.

However, if for some reason you change `loopEnd` in the loop like this ..

```
    Dim loopStart As Integer = 0
    Dim loopEnd As Integer = 10
    For i As Integer = loopStart To loopEnd
        loopEnd = 90000000
    Next
```

The loop will still only execute 11 times. This is because the parameters of the actual loop are set the first time. This creates a small problem when you're removing items from a list

In the list of items above, we have 11 items. So the `.Count` of the items = 11. Because the index number of the last item is `10`, we will need to tell the loop that the end point is `ListBox1.Items.Count - 1` No problem.

So we go through the loop, find a matching number and remove it. Now we have a problem. When we remove an item, all the items further down the list are shuffled up to the next index.

E.G If we remove the number at index 5, the number that was at index six will now be at index 5, the number that was at index 7 will now be at index 6 and so on.

And now that an item has been removed, the count of the number of items will now be 10 and the last item will be at index 9. Because the end point of the loop is still 10 we will get an error when the program tries to access item 10. It doesn't exist.

The way to solve this is to go backwards through the loop.

```
Dim loopStart As Integer = 0
Dim loopEnd As Integer = Listbox1.Items.Count
For i As Integer = loopEnd To loopStart Step -1

Next
```

If we start at index 10, and go on to 9 and so on, if we get to item 5 and remove it, all the items further down the list will be shuffled up one. The next time the loop goes round, we will be at item 4 then 3 then 2 then 1 then 0. Because the end point of the loop is 0 and the item at index 0 still exists, the loop completes successfully and no problem.

So, the final code with your `If .. Then` statement will look like this ..

```
If Integer.TryParse(strInput, intNumRemoved) Then 'Converting the user input from InputBox to an Integer
    For i As Integer = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If intNumRemoved = CInt(ListBox1.Items(i)) Then
            ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i)
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Hope this helps.

By the way. My comment in your other question about not using controls as your primary way of storing data applies here as well. Instead of using a ListBox, you should store all your items in a `List(Of integer)` and work on that, then clear the Listbox and add the items from the List.